# How to get notification whenever a character is inputted into NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa

I'm a little rusty on my Cocoa, so bear with me on terminology and such.

I want to write something that is essentially a reverse spell checker. As in, if a word is spell correctly, then for random words it changes it to a misspelled version. Harmless prank to play on someone.

So then, my main hitch is that I have no idea how to do this (major problem, I know). I like the way that textedit performs on-the-fly spellchecking, but I'd like to incorporate that sort of behavior into the generic behavior of the NSTextField. Is there some way for an application to be notified whenever a character is input into an NSTextField?

EDIT: My aim is to make this system-wide, as in any NSTextField in the system would get this behavior as a matter of inheritance. I'm open to some **serious** hacking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: attach a delegate to the NSTextField control, and implement

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Note that NSTextField uses the shared field editor to edit text, which is a NSText object. You might be able to manipulate that to do what you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my post, but I want to make this a system-wide behavior, in that every NSTextField would exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I sure hope that isn't possible!

Comment: I mentioned in my edit that I'm up for some serious hacking, if need be. I can go all the way down to the kernel level if I have to (although that would take this from a prank to a rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea!  This should be fairly easy to do.  First you have to decide if you want to use `NSTextField` or `NSTextView`.  TextEdit.app uses `NSTextView` which is appropriate for more extensive word processing-type tasks.  `NSTextField` is more for smaller, minimally-formatted chunks of text.  There's lots of ways to tackle this, but I'll give you a couple.

For `NSTextField`, set your controller object to be the delegate for the text field and override the `controlTextDidChange:` method.  Whenever the user types a character into the text field, you'll get this message.  You can then modify the field's string to introduce the misspelled word.

For `NSTextView`, you can activate spell checking and use the text view's delegate method `textView:didCheckTextInRange:types:options:results:orthography:wordCount:`.  You should be able to modify the results of the spell check.